# Reinstall client side SSL certificate

Tags: ubuntu, ssl

I have an Ubuntu server on which, *a long time ago*, I secured access to a certain area, 'foo', via *client side* browser certificates.

I've just tried to access said site for the first time in a while, to be told that my certificate has expired.

I remember self signing the certificate, so it's not something that needs re-buying - although I'm not clear if it's the server certificate or client certificate that needs recreating.

The only tip is that `/etc/ssl/` contains the following:

```
mainsite.ca-bundle
mainsite.crt
mainsite.csr
mainsite.key
server.crt
foo_cacert.pem
foo_server_key.pem
foo_server_cert.pem
```

And my apache SSL conf contains (among other things):

```
SSLEngine on
SSLOptions +StrictRequire
#SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/mainsite.crt
#SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/mainsite.key
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/foo_server_cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/foo_server_key.pem
SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/foo_cacert.pem
```

How would I go about refreshing the certificate on the server and re-isntalling on my local machine?

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://www.impetus.us/~rjmooney/projects/misc/clientcertauth.html) should get you going